# Agregación con operaciones matematicas MongoDB

Tags: base-de-datos, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

Estoy tratando de hacer la siguiente consulta:
10% de descuento en cada uno de los precios de los artículos almacenados en mis documentos.

Estoy usando la siguiente agregación, pero no logro hacerla funcionar

```
db.tienda.aggregate( [ 
    { 
        $project: { 
            "Productos.Nombre": 1,
            "Productos.Precio": 1, 
            "Descuento": { 
                $sum: [ 
                    "$Productos.Precio", 
                    { 
                        $multiply: [ 
                            "$Productos.Precio", 
                             -0.10 
                        ]
                    } 
                ] 
            } 
        } 
    }
] )
```

Mi documento es:

```
db.tienda.insert( [
{ 
 "Codigo": 1, "Nombre": "Fabrica comida", 
 "Productos": [ { "Codigo": "C1", "Nombre": "Papitas", "Precio": 1.20 }, { 
 "Codigo": "C2", "Nombre": "Perro caliente", "Precio": 3.10 }, { "Codigo": 
 "C3", "Nombre": "Hamburguesa", "Precio": 4 }, { "Codigo": "C4", "Nombre": 
 "Pizza", "Precio": 2.60 }, { "Codigo": "C5", "Nombre": "Malteada", 
 "Precio": 3 } ] 
},
{ 
 "Codigo": 2, "Nombre": "Tecnologia", 
 "Productos": [ { "Codigo": "T1", "Nombre": "Producto 8", "Precio": 300 }, { 
 "Codigo": "T2", "Nombre": "Smart TV", "Precio": 1200 }, { "Codigo": "T3", 
 "Nombre": "Teatro en casa", "Precio": 250 }, { "Codigo": "T4", "Nombre": 
 "Laptop", "Precio": 560 }, { "Codigo": "T5", "Nombre": "DVD", "Precio": 160 
 } ] 
},
{ 
 "Codigo": 3, "Nombre": "Deportes", 
 "Productos": [ { "Codigo": "D1", "Nombre": "Balon de futbol", "Precio": 20 
 }, { "Codigo": "D2", "Nombre": "Bate de baseball", "Precio": 49.99 }, { 
 "Codigo": "D3", "Nombre": "Canilleras", "Precio": 7.80 }, { "Codigo": "D4", 
 "Nombre": "Equipo de buceo", "Precio": 650 }, { "Codigo": "D5", "Nombre": 
 "Raqueta de tenis", "Precio": 25.50 } ] 
},
{ 
 "Codigo": 4, "Nombre": "Muebles", 
 "Productos": [ { "Codigo": "M1", "Nombre": "Armario", "Precio": 330 }, { 
 "Codigo": "M2", "Nombre": "Mesa de centro", "Precio": 60 }, { "Codigo": 
 "M3", "Nombre": "Comedor", "Precio": 1090 }, { "Codigo": "M4", "Nombre": 
 "Sala-Comedor", "Precio": 860 }, { "Codigo": "M5", "Nombre": "Lampara", 
 "Precio": 40 } ] 
},
{ 
 "Codigo": 5, "Nombre": "Hobbies", 
 "Productos": [ { "Codigo": "H1", "Nombre": "Mesa de hockey", "Precio": 320 
 }, { "Codigo": "H2", "Nombre": "Mesa de ping-pong", "Precio": 610 }, { 
 "Codigo": "H3", "Nombre": "Mesa de billar", "Precio": 2400 }, { "Codigo": 
 "H4", "Nombre": "Consola de videojuegos", "Precio": 220 }, { "Codigo": 
 "H5", "Nombre": "Mesa de poker", "Precio": 1650 } ] 
}
] )
```

¿Alguna idea de por qué pueda estar fallando o cómo puedo lograr un resultado correcto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para obtener los resultados deseados debemos tomar en cuenta el tipo de datos que deseamos manipular en la agregación y en base a eso construir nuestra etapa.

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea realizar una consulta sobre una colección que tiene una lista de productos anidada. Se requiere que la consulta devuelva un documento que contenga la lista de productos con un campo adicional (por producto) llamado `Descuento`. En dicho campo se debe mostrar el valor del descuento aplicado al precio del producto.

Los documentos se almacenan en una colección llamada `tienda`, y los mismos tienen la siguiente estructura:

```
{
    "Codigo"   : <Tipo String que representa el código de la tienda>,
    "Nombre"   : <Tipo String que representa el nombre de la tienda>,
    "Productos": <Tipo Array que almacena una lista de productos>
}
```

Un documento de producto tiene la siguiente estructura:

```
{
    "Codigo": <Tipo String que representa el código del producto>,
    "Nombre": <Tipo String que representa el nombre del producto>,
    "Precio": <Tipo Double que representa el precio del producto>
}
```

**SOLUCIÓN**

La agregación que intentas usar no funciona debido a que realizas el procedimiento sobre el tipo de dato incorrecto.

El error que devuelve tu agregación es el siguiente:

```
"errmsg" : "$multiply only supports numeric types, not array"
```

Y es que el campo `Productos` es de tipo `Array` como vimos anteriormente. Debemos entonces utilizar métodos que nos permitan trabajar sobre campos de tipo `Array`. En la [documentación](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#array-expression-operators) podemos encontrar todos los operadores disponibles en MongoDB para el manejo de tipos `Array` en procesos de Agregación.

Debido a que el resultado esperado será un tipo `Array`, usaremos el operador [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/#map-aggregation).

El método `$map` tiene la siguiente sintaxis:

```
{ $map: { input: <expression>, as: <string>, in: <expression> } }
```

Donde:

- `input`: Expresión que retorna un tipo `Array`. En este caso pasaremos como expresión el nombre del campo que contiene la lista de productos.
- `as`: Elemento opcional tipo `String`. Es el nombre que le daremos a la variable que representa el elemento del `Array` que vamos a iterar. Si no lo especificamos, el nombre por defecto del elemento será `this`.
- `in`: Expresión que se aplica a cada elemento del `Array` de entrada (`input`). La expresión hace referencia a cada elemento iterable utilizando el nombre de variable especificado en el campo `as`.

Podemos ver en la [documentación](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#aggregation-expressions), las expresiones válidas en MongoDB.

Usaremos la ruta del campo ([*field path*](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/glossary/#term-field-path)) para obtener el valor del campo `Nombre` y el valor del campo `Precio`.

Llamaremos a nuestra variable `prod`, para referirnos a un elemento del `Array`. Entonces, para obtener el nombre del producto que estamos iterando, basta con acceder a `$$prod.Nombre`. Igualmente si deseamos el precio del producto, usaremos `$$prod.Precio`.

También utilizaremos el operador [`$multiply`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/multiply/index.html) para calcular el valor del descuento aplicado.

Podemos armar la expresión que vamos a pasar al campo `in` de la siguiente forma:

```
{
    'Nombre': '$$prod.Nombre',
    'Precio': '$$prod.Precio',
    'Descuento': {
        $mutliply: ['$$prod.precio', -0.1]
    }
}
```

Ahora ya tenemos todos los elementos y podemos armar nuestra agregación.

Dado que el método `$map` devuelve un tipo `Array`, vamos a nombrar `Productos` a nuestra variable que recibirá el resultado de `$map`.

```
db.tienda.aggregate(
  [
    {
      $project: {
        Productos: {
          $map: {
            input: '$Productos',
            as: 'prod',
            in: {
              'Nombre': '$$prod.Nombre',
              'Precio': '$$prod.Precio',
              'Descuento': {$multiply: ['$$prod.Precio', -0.1]}
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
);
```

Al ejecutar la agregación anterior, usando los datos proporcionados en la pregunta, se obtiene el siguiente resultado: (se muestra un solo documento)

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d1c565000143c7c2280978f"),
    "Productos" : [
        {
            "Nombre" : "Mesa de hockey",
            "Precio" : 320,
            "Descuento" : -32
        },
        {
            "Nombre" : "Mesa de ping-pong",
            "Precio" : 610,
            "Descuento" : -61
        },
        {
            "Nombre" : "Mesa de billar",
            "Precio" : 2400,
            "Descuento" : -240
        },
        {
            "Nombre" : "Consola de videojuegos",
            "Precio" : 220,
            "Descuento" : -22
        },
        {
            "Nombre" : "Mesa de poker",
            "Precio" : 1650,
            "Descuento" : -165
        }
    ]
}
```

Espero que esto sea lo que estabas buscando y te ayude a aclarar las dudas.